# Why photons don't interact with magnetic field of a permanent magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, magnetic-fields, photons

Since **photons are electromagnetic** in nature having component of magnetic field, they should be **attracted or repelled** by a permanent magnet. But for instance,  a beam of laser light is not seen doing so in *normal life*.
Edit1: Please note that I'm **not asking** about interections described by Lorentz Force **(v×Bq)** that is deflection of charged particle in external magnetic field. The interaction I'm concerned with is similar to two permanent magnets.They are not charged  particles but still interact with other magnetic fields because they themselves have magnetic field, similar to photon has.

Answer (score 1):

No, photons have no charge, so they aren't deflected by a magnet. However, the polarization of light *is* influenced by a magnetic field. This is known as the [Faraday effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_effect).

From Wikipedia:

> The Faraday effect causes a polarization rotation which is proportional to the projection of the magnetic field along the direction of the light propagation.
>
> Discovered by Michael Faraday in 1845, the Faraday effect was the first experimental evidence that light and electromagnetism are related.
>
> The Faraday effect is caused by left and right circularly polarized waves propagating at slightly different speeds, a property known as circular birefringence

Comment: Thanks for answering. I understand deflection due to Lorentz force (**B×vq**) act on charged particles. But how I thought of this question is in this way. Two magnets attract/repel because their magnetic fields interact with each others magnetic field. They are not charge either. Then why photon's magnetic field don't interact with magnetic field of permanent magnet.

Answer (score 0):

[Photons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon#Physical_properties) don't have an electric charge.
That's why they don't interact with electric and magnetic fields.
(You can say, photons *are* the electromagnetic field.)
Photons interact only with charged particles.

Comment: Nit: photons interact with particles which have mass, albeit so weakly that it takes a black hole to demonstrate the effect

Comment: Nit2: @CarlWitthoft It doesn't have to be a black hole - the deflection of light rays by Sun has been observed more than a century ago.

Comment: @stafusa yes; thanks for the correction!

Answer (score -1):

Photons are emitted by charges.
Charges have both an electric field and a magnetic dipole field.
The photons emitted by the charges have an oscillating electric field component and an oscillating magnetic field component.

When passing through a crystal lattice whose molecular structure spacing is comparable to or a multiple of the wavelength of the photons, a splitting of the light with outgoing polarised photons occurs in some natural materials.

Faraday achieves the same effect with materials that have been placed under the influence of an external magnetic field. This leads to the alignment of the magnetic dipoles of molecules and atoms and the effect was outgoing polarised photons.

A magnetic field itself must be switched on and off at twice the photon frequency. This is impossible and therefore a photon cannot interact with a permanent magnet.